# Ocultar Pop Up Lightbox div ao Clicar em um Elemento/botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, script

Eu fiz um anúncio no meu site, para Multiuso.

Eu gostaria de fazer um "PopUp" (*PopOver*, ou conhecido *Modal*) personalizado meu, no caso criei uma `div`.

O ID da `div` é `adonsite`, e eu gostaria de fechar ela ao clicar em outra `div`.

Existe algum Script para isso?

Comment: Podes mostrar o código do modal que tens? é teu ou o do jQuery? tem overflay ou nõ? o botão para fechar está dentro ou fora do Modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.stopPropagation();` deve fazer o trabalho como por exemplo [aqui neste link](http://jsfiddle.net/oqeza0f6/).
No entanto usar `.stopPropagation();` as vezes pode ser mau.

Então eu faria isto de outra forma. Primeiro iria criar uma "camada" de cobertura `#overlay` que irá cobrir toda a página por completo e que será também usada como um botão **"close"**, assim quando clicarmos em qualquer sitio desta camada/div `#overlay` iremos ocultar ambos, a div `#overlay` e também o suposto anúncio.

Em seguida dentro da `#overlay` iria então criar uma nova `div class="white-content"` que irá conter todo o conteúdo informativo como texto, anúncios, e até outro botão **"close"** se quiseres para poder fechar esta caixa. Este é um sistema que muitos Plugins Lightbox utilizam.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/rfa3jh2x/

```js
// Ao clicar nos elementos #overlay ou #close fecha a caixa
$( '#overlay, #close').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#adonsite, #overlay").hide();
});

$( '#show').on('click', function(event) {
    $("#adonsite, #overlay").show();
});
```

```css
#close {float: right;}

.white-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 16px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); /* Podes remover esta linha se quiseres um Background transparente */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.advertise {
  background: #5DB0EE;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="show">Show lightbox</button>

<div id="adonsite" style="display:none">
    <div class="white-content">
        <button id="close">Close</button>
            <p>Clique no botão (Close) ou em qualquer sítio fora da caixa branca para ocultar isto.</p>
            <div class="advertise">AD</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Obrigado. É Isso que eu procuro :)

Comment: De nada @HugoMarcelo =)

Answer (score 1):

Caso você esteja utilizando jQuery, execute o comando a seguir para esconder o `div`:

```
$("#divId").hide();
```

Caso seja um [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) do `jquery-ui` aberto, execute o seguinte comando para fechar o *dialog*:

```
$("#divId").dialog("close");
```

Caso utilize Javascript puro, execute o seguinte comando para esconder um `div`:

```
document.getElementById("divId").style.display = 'none';
```

Para os casos citados acima `divId` é o identificador do `div`, por exemplo, o `div` a seguir será fechado:

```
<div id="divId">.....</div>
```