# banner flutuante que cobre a pagina inteira

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

quero um banner ou uma div que fique no meio da minha pagina é que nesse banner tenha um botão para fecha ele é que enquanto não fecha ele não seja possivel ter acesso a nada da pagina..

resumo:uma div que quando entra na minha pagina ele apareça e bloqueie todo conteúdo da pagina é só libere quando clica no botão fecha,Nele irei colocar uma propaganda :)

não entendo nada de programação então não tenho um exemplo espero que de para entende obg...

Comment: Já [tens aqui uma solução](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/64636/11886) desse género, basta removeres o `style="display:none"` do código HTML e tirares o `#overlay` do código jQuery se quiseres que apenas o botão seja o ***trigger*** para fechar o Pop Up.

Comment: Olá @Edu. Acredito que seja interessante dar um lida na ajuda sobre como fazer perguntas no Stackoverflow: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
O SO é uma comunidade que te ajuda a resolver problemas com seu código, mas no seu caso você ainda não tem um código, por isso seria interessante pesquisar no próprio site por exemplos similares, ou algum tutorial mais completo de desenvolvimento já que você ainda não programa (esse por exemplo: http://www.devmedia.com.br/jquery-dialog-dica/28682).